# БД. Андроид. SQLite. Проверка на пустоту

Tags: android

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как изменить этот метод?Чтобы если в таблице нет элемента с таким number возвращался false и иначе true?

```
 public boolean Null(int number) {
      boolean check=true;
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER, COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH }, COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(number) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor!=null)
        check=false;


        return check;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        return false;
}
return true
```

Методы в `Java` не принято называть с заглавной (большой) буквы. Кроме того, его название ну абсолютно не отображает того, что он должен делать. Назовите его, например `hasRecord`, или `contains`. Можно убрать переменную `check` вообще.